# Intellij : Not able to enable persist view for jooq-hibernate project

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea, jooq

From my intellij(version# 2020.1), I am trying to enable persist view on intellij for my java-spring-boot project ( jdk11, spring boot 2.3.0.RELEASE ) using jooq-hibernate for back end. That will help me generating the code for entities.

Here are the dependencies that I used in build.gradle:

```
 //Spring Dependencies
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

//postges
implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.14'

//flyway
compile 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core:6.4.4'

//jooq dependency
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jooq'

//test
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testRuntimeClasspath 'com.h2database:h2'
```

Any idea how to enable that for this kind of project?

Comment: What exactly is not working for you?

Comment: not finding persist view anywhere.

Comment: Did you follow https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-the-persistence-tool-window.html? Did you enable JPA or Hibernate support per the documentation?

Comment: Tried. However, that specific plugin is not available. I installed "jpa support" instead. That did not help.

Comment: Do you use IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate? Do you see Hibernate plug-in bundled and enabled? https://i.imgur.com/AxItORa.png .